# Finishing all other activities while keeping MainActivity running

Tags: java, android, kotlin

First, I've seen all other questions and answers regarding something similar to this but what I need is a bit different.

I need to be able to close all running activities in the background (They are running a thread and when I go back to MainActivity they are still running)

So what I want is when I return to MainActivity I need OnResume to clear or at least finish all the other activities running without running a new activity or closing the MainActivity.

Is this possible?

Comment: did you mean close all other activities in the stack?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just need to start your MainActivity with theses flags: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |  FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.